# Plotting an inequality involving $|\arg(z)|$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to plot an inequality which involves $|\arg(z)|$, however I don't understand how the modulus affects the $\arg(z).$

The inequality being $$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq|\arg(z)|\leq\frac{\pi}{2},\quad 1\leq|z|\leq2. $$

Comment: You also have to plot $-\frac{\pi}{4} \geq \arg z \geq -\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Take that annulus $\;1\le |z|\le2\;$ and draw two radial lines that'll cross it , one for each of $\;\frac\pi4\,,\,\,\frac\pi2\;$ . The intersected zone within the annulus is *almost* what you want, as you **must also** do the same with radial lines one for each of $\;-\frac\pi2\,,\,\,-\frac\pi4\;$ . The union of both regions is what you want.

Comment: Thank you!! :) @DonAntonio